# How to let processes crash silently in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

When a process crashes I get a dialog that asks me what to do with the application (check for a solution or skip without any actions).
How can I completely avoid Windows to complain about a crash so the process simply is killed without any prompt or similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in the solutions to this question: [How do I disable the 'Debug / Close Application' dialog on Windows Vista?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396369/how-do-i-disable-the-debug-close-application-dialog-on-windows-vista)

I would assume another way to get rid of that is to [disable Windows error reporting](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7863/disable-error-reporting-in-xp-vista-and-windows-7/).

For Windows 7, you'd want to set it to **Never check for solutions** in the **Problem Reporting Settings**:
[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, but do you thinks it completely suppresses any dialog that could show up on a crash?

Comment: @nepa: This should only disable dialogs that Windows might pop up in case of an application crash (uncaught exception to be precise). In case the application itself has an internal error handling mechanism, this approach will have no effect on it. But I doubt any other solution would.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't cause the process to end silently. when you run it in a batch it doesn't continue. is there some other method?

Comment: @nepa: It doesn't? Then what **does** it do? What are you seeing? What does "*when you run it in batch*" mean? What does "*it doesn't continue*" mean? What are you actually seeing that you're trying to avoid seeing? A screenshot sometimes helps a lot :)

Comment: i'm starting an app with a batch file (.bat). when the app crashes Windows shows me "NAME_OF_APP doesn't work any more - a problem caused the execution of the application to stop. close the application." and a button "close application" (translated from german). when everything would be right it just closed the app and continued the execution of the batch file...

Comment: @nepa: Did you also apply the [registry changes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/396510/259953) that were suggested in the question over on SO?

Comment: sorry, i missed the last link. as it's the real solution and the first link doesn't do it i would put it in the beginning. but now it works, thanks :)